# how to create new columns from a list of columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have an existing dataframe. And I have a list.

```
my_list = ['col_10', 'col_11', 'col_12', 'col_13']
```

I want to add new columns in my dataframe that are have these column names, the same value `placeholder`

I thought this would do the trick:

```
for column_names in my_list:
   my_dataframe[column_names] = 'placeholder'
```

but I get this error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

EDIT: This code worked once I realized that my_dataframe was not a dataframe

Comment: That should in theory work, are you sure everything is named correctly and that it is indeed a dataframe?
If so we will need some example data so we can replicate your issue

Comment: Seems `my_dataframe` is not actually a dataframe.

Comment: Please include the code that you used to initialize `my_dataframe`.

Comment: @BigBen I realized that you were correct my_dataframe wasnt a dataframe